# What do dyadic product have to do with polynomial multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials

I'm reading things about RLWE (Ring Learning With Errors) cryptography, and it relies heavily on polynomial multiplication modulo something. [There's this line of code from Microsoft's SEAL RLWE library](https://github.com/microsoft/SEAL/blob/d045f1beff96dff0fccc7fa0c5acb1493a65338c/native/src/seal/util/rlwe.cpp#L231) called

```
dyadic_product_coeffmod(
                        u.get() + i * coeff_count, public_key.data().data(j) + i * coeff_count, coeff_count,
                        coeff_modulus[i], destination.data(j) + i * coeff_count);
```

It looks like it multiplies 2 polynomials using the dyadic product. However, looking at the code, it looks like it's doing simply $a_i*b_i$ where $a_i$ and $b_i$ are the polynomial coefficients.

What is happening?

*PS*: the polynomials coefficients might be in [RNS form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_number_system)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are using a number theoretic transform (NTT) and the convolution property to replace polynomial multiplication (convolution of coefficients of the two polynomials you are multiplying) by termwise product in the Fourier domain.

> The number theoretic transform may be meaningful in the ring
> ${\mathbb  {Z}}/m,$ even when the modulus $m$ is not prime, provided a principal root of order $n$ exists. Special cases of the number theoretic transform such as the Fermat Number Transform ($m = 2^k+1$), used by the Schönhage–Strassen algorithm, or Mersenne Number Transform ($m = 2k − 1$) use a composite modulus.

NTT is a special case of Fourier (DFT) https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform_(general). It has no rounding, it is exact, very important here.

Such a transform exists when a primitive root of unity of the right order exists. See p.2 of
[this paper](https://acsweb.ucsd.edu/%7Esag076/papers/dac20_cryptopim.pdf) for an RWLE example.

**Edit**: Dyadic product is simply the term used in the
[SEAL manual](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2017/11/sealmanual-2-3-1.pdf) to denote the termwise product in the Fourier (NTT) domain. So if the NTT coefficients are in the lists $(a(\lambda)),(b(\lambda))$ the dyadic product is the list $(a(\lambda) b(\lambda)).$

This is a somewhat unusual use of that term.

Comment: but what does it have to do with dyadic?

Comment: Dyadic product is simply the term the micosoft SEAL document uses to describe termwise multiplication.